# Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for

Tags: docker, centos, docker-registry

I am new to docker and cannot understand these errors. So, Please let me know if any more information is needed.
`

```
[root@localhost docker]# systemctl start docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

systemctl status docker.service` output:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Sun 2023-04-02 01:34:47 CEST; 5min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 9060 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --registry-mirror=<your accelerate address> -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 9060 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

`journalctl -xe`output

```
Apr 02 01:34:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 02 01:34:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 02 01:34:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Apr 02 01:34:42 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.
Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain dockerd[9060]: Status: invalid argument "<your" for "--registry-mirror" flag: invalid mirror: unsupported scheme "" in "%3Cyour"
Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain dockerd[9060]: See 'dockerd --help'., Code: 125
Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Apr 02 01:34:44 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has finished shutting down.
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Apr 02 01:34:47 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
lines 2500-2554/2554 (END)
```

Docker version:

```
Docker version 24.0.0-beta.1, build 33961a7
```

Linux kernel version:

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-1160.88.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 7 15:41:52 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

CentOS version:

```
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

I notice `journalctl -xe`output said that `Status: invalid argument "<your" for "--registry-mirror" flag: invalid mirror: unsupported scheme "" in "%3Cyour"`, but I can't find where to modify it.
I have tried to reinstall docker, delete the `daemon.json` but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is set in one of the systemd unit files. You can see the files used to define the unit in the status output:

```
# systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running)  ...
```

Docker owns the `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` file, so you don't want to edit this. However, files in /etc/systemd/ will persist between installs. After editing one of these files, you need to load them back into systemd with `systemctl daemon-reload` before trying to restart the service.

Comment: Thank you very much! I followed your guidence and succeeded in starting docker. Now the status of it is active(running). But when I entered "docker info", there is still an error.                   ```

Comment: Thank you very much! I followed your guidence and succeeded in starting docker. Now the status of it is active(running). But when I entered "docker info", there is still an error.                   ```Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Status: invalid argument "<your" for "--registry-mirror" flag: invalid mirror: unsupported scheme "" in "%3Cyour"
See 'dockerd --help'., Code: 125
docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Unit docker.service entered failed state.
docker.service failed.
```

Comment: That output is not expected from a `docker info` command. Please raise it as a separate question.